# Entire function with bounded sequence of distinct real numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, entire-functions

Problem: Suppose that $f$ is an entire function and that there is a bounded sequence of distinct real numbers $\{ a_n \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $f(a_n)\in \mathbb{R}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $f(x)\in \mathbb{R}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

**My attempt:** Since $\{ a_n \}$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers, there exists a convergent subsequence $\{ a_{n_k} \} \rightarrow a \in \mathbb{R}$. By $f$ entire, we can consider its Taylor expansion at $a$: $$f(z) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (z-a)^n$$ If we can show that $f^{(n)}(a) \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ then we are done since all the terms are real so plugging in a real number $x$ into $f(z)$ will output a real value.

Since $f$ is entire, it is a continuous function so $f(a) = f(\lim\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty} a_{n_k}) = \lim\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty} f(a_{n_k}) \in \mathbb{R}$ since $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $f(a_{n_k}) \in \mathbb{R}$ by assumption. This implies that $$f'(a) = \lim\limits_{z\rightarrow a} \frac{f(z) - f(a)}{z-a} = \lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(a_{n_k}) - f(a)}{a_{n_k}-a} \in \mathbb{R}$$ since $f(a_{n_k}), f(a), a_{n_k}, a \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Question:** How can I show that $f^{(n)}(a) \in \mathbb{R}$ for $n \geq 2$ from here? I have not used the "distinct real numbers" assumption yet.

Comment: consider the analytic function $g(z)=f(z)-\bar f(\bar z)$; the hypothesis is that $g$ is zero on a set with accumulation points, so it must be zero by the identity theorem which means precisely that $f(x) \in \mathbb R$ when $x \in \mathbb R$

Comment: @Conrad Does the "distinct" assumption matter here? Thanks for the quick comment.

Comment: @Conrad Sorry, also does the identity theorem tell us that $g(z) = 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$? Therefore the power series of $f(z)$ and $\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ are equal hence the coefficients of the power series are real and so we are done?

Comment: the distinct is essential since that allows us to conclude that they have an accumulation point (by definition, an accumulation point is precisely a limit point of a sequence of distinct numbers) the identity theorem is valid for complex  analytic functions on domains, so in particular for entire functions - the proof is standard showing that the set of points where all the Taylor coefficients are zero is nonempty, open and closed - for entire functions the proof is even simpler of course as the Taylor series is valid everywhere, so enough to show it has all zero coefficients at a point

Comment: @Conrad Quite amazing that a single accumulation point will tell you that $f(z) = \overline{f(\overline{z})}$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$... Thank you!

Comment: This comes from the power series since if wlog $0$ is accumulation point of zeroes then $f(z)=cz^k+..., c\ne 0$ but then $g(z)=f(z)/z^k$ is continuous (here power series is crucial so $k$ nonnegative integer and $z^k$ well defined around zero) and then we get contradiction $g(a_k)=0$ converge to $c\ne 0$ so power series is zero on its convergence disc - from here if function entire so convergence disc is full plane, done, if not entire the connectedness argument above shows $f$ zero on the connected open set of definition containing zero